Do any countries formally recognize the "Isaaq genocide" as a genocide?
I'm curious what level of international recognition does the Isaaq genocide have. (Those were events during the Somaliland War of Independence.) Wikipedia doesn't say whether it's explicitly recognized as a genocide by some/any countries. Do some countries [quasi-]officially recognize it as a genocide, e.g. in some parliamentary proclamations etc., as it's been the case with some other genocides? (I'm guessing at least Somaliland does recognize it like that.)

The article clearly says that the UN found it to be a genocide. So to be clear... You're looking for individual countries officially acknowledging that, as opposed to international bodies?

@BrianZ: An OHCHR 'preliminary' report isn't quite the UN. It's not even the UNGA, where countries vote on something, on the record.

@BrianZ: apparently even the Srebrenica genocide might not have been recognized by the latter (UNGA), given that there are advocacy groups pushing for that https://www.aegistrust.org/aegis-trust-supports-unga-srebrenica-genocide-resolution/ ; http://instituteforgenocide.org/igc-asks-all-member-states-of-the-un-general-assembly-support-to-unga-resolution-on-srebrenica/ (Yeah, that res asks for a remembrance day, so might not be the same thing.)

@BrianZ: still not sure about UNGA, but at UNSC "In 2015, Russia vetoed a British-sponsored U.N. Security Council resolution that would have condemned the Srebrenica massacre as a "crime of genocide," with Russia's permanent representative to the U.N., dismissing the proposed resolution as "not constructive, confrontational, and politically motivated."" https://www.newsweek.com/heavy-responsibility-faces-un-general-assembly-starts-opinion-1825090 So, yeah, what OHCHR says sometimes stays there.

Just a note of context, regarding the international community, there is a lot more attention and commentary given to international conflicts over entirely domestic ones.

@DavidS: well, Kosovo was also an 'internal conflict', until it wasn't. It seems to me this genocide was pretty close to being the founding/justifying event for the modern Somaliland. Except they found no friends, unlike Kosovo.
